# Spring Data REST: repository multiple value request parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Could anyone help me please? In fact, I have a project using Spring boot/Spring Data-REST. In my custom repository interface I create a new method like the following:

```
@Query("SELECT h FROM History h WHERE " +
        " (:fromDate IS NULL OR h.date >= :fromDate)" +
        " AND (:toDate IS NULL OR h.date <= :toDate)" +
        " AND (:ids IS NULL OR h.id IN :ids)")
 Page<History> findHistoryByCriteria(
        @Param("fromDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy") Date fromDate,
        @Param("toDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy") Date toDate,
        @Param("ids") List<Integer> ids);
```

When I call it using the URL **http://{hostname}:{port}/{context}/...?fromDate=08/01/2016&toDate=08/31/2016&ids[]=1&ids[]=2**, I get wrong result. In log I get

```
TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [null]
TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [6] as [INTEGER] - [null]
```

and if I try to use **http://{hostname}:{port}/{context}/...?fromDate=08/01/2016&toDate=08/31/2016&ids=2**, it returned me a valid result.

If I try to use  **http://{hostname}:{port}/{context}/...?fromDate=08/01/2016&toDate=08/31/2016&ids=2&ids=3**, I get an exception

```
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
```

How should I call an URL containing a multiple value parameter (array) or what should I do to make it treating the parameter as an array or a collection?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Finally, I saw how to solve it. For everyone having the same issues, the URL format to send an array value with Spring is **ids=oneId,anotherId** instead of **ids[]=oneId&ids[]=anotherId** or **ids=oneId&ids=anotherId**

Answer (score 4):

For those of you coming here a few years later from when this question was asked, and since it is the top of the google search results, I ran into the same issue and figured out the following:

If you use a Collection type as an argument in your repository method, the only way to get SD Rest to transform it correctly is to pass the value as a comma separated string in a single query parameter as Rindra above comment states. It will not accept multiple parameters of the same name with different values. This is because the conversion code is not smart enough to know that the collection it was provided (e.g. List) is different than the collection that is expected (e.g. List) as it does not look at the inner collection type. It simply sees that a List is expected and a List was provided, so it skips any attempt to convert.

That said, if you instead use an array (Integer[]) instead of a collection, then you can pass the values as a comma separated string in a single query parameter AND as single values in multiple query parameters.

It comes down to the available registered converters in the conversion service. There is a StringToCollectionConverter in the case of "?ids=123,432" and a CollectionToArrayConverter in the case of "?ids=123&ids=432"